# NSDictionary is causing a Thread 1 breakpoint when setting parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I'm trying to receive a result after sending a base64 image over to a website, where it should be able to analyse the image. Whenever I try this though I get a thread 1 break point occuring at

```
NSDictionary *data = @{@"data" : [image base64Encoding]};
```

I'm not sure what it is producing such an error, but it has consistently been doing so.

```
- (void)contentFilteringAnalysis:(UIImage *)image completionHandler:(LQDictionaryCompletionBlock)completion{

NSDictionary *data = @{@"data" : [image base64Encoding]};
[self.manager POST:[self urlStringFor:kIndicoContentFiltering]
        parameters:data
           success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
               if (completion) {
                   completion(responseObject, nil);
               }
           }
           failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
               if (completion) {
                   completion(nil, error);
               }
           }];
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

EDIT
[image: thread error]

Comment: What does the exception log/message say?

Comment: it was just `(lldb)`

Comment: no it wasn't. go google what LLDB is.

Comment: if it's just an (lldb) then you simply put a breakpoint in Xcode on this line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your `UIImage` into `NSData` before, something like:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

NSDictionary *data = @{@"data" : [imageData base64Encoding]};
```

Comment: in reference to your comment,
I've tried putting a break point onto this line and it still crashes it seems as if it is crashing the second i try to receive @"data"

Comment: please take a look into your screenshot, you do not use imageData, but still trying to encode image which may cause the problem.

Comment: so i should use imagedata instead?